# Multiple qTip2 on the same element

Tags: qtip2

Calling .qtip twice on the same element erases the previous qtip. Is it possible to have 2 styles of qtip on the same element (one is right click, one is mouse over)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant have 2 on the same element but you can wrap the element in a span and call qtip on that with a different trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I just upvoted Bruian's answer as I have tried the other technique that I found through Googling which says to create a qtip and to add removeData('qtip') before adding another one :

```
$('.selector')
    .qtip() // tooltip 1
    .removeData('qtip') // remove it's data
    .qtip(); // tooltip 2
```

This technique will work for simple cases, but you are setting yourself up for a lot of problems down the line with duplicate ids and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

For those still interested using one description for multiple item. You can use this method:

1) Make one div with all the description item you want.for example:

```
 <div id='description' class='describe_content' style='display:none;'>
   <div id='test'>this is description</div>
   <div id='test2'>teeest</div>
 </div>
```

2) Use the following code for the qtip. You can see the comment on what each item do.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','input ,select ,dl , .dropdown2 .mutliSelect li',function(event)
 {
  string = $("#test2");
$(this).qtip({
    overwrite: true, //to allow it the same item be paste to other part.
    position: {
            my: pos[pos_c+3],  // Position my top left...
            at: pos[pos_c], // at the bottom right of...
            target: $(this) // my target
    },
    content: {
    text: string,   // the text
    },
    show:{
      event: event.type, //use the same show event as the one that triggered
      ready: true      //show the tooltip as soon as it's bound.
    },
     'font-size': 16
  },event);// have to pass event as second parameter, because qtips positioning
}
```

Note that the position is just a extra option, you could remove it if you want.